# Linux binary can't find shared library, but works while running in strace

Tags: shared-libraries, strace

(Note: names of the binary and binary and library below are obfuscated to protect the innocent. ;-) The app is proprietary under NDA but the behavior may not depend on it.)

I have a Linux binary which prints the following error when run:

> binary: error while loading shared libraries: libshared.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Which is confusing on its own since libshared.so is in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. However,

- The library is found correctly when running `ldd binary` (i.e., the ldd output points to the file location)
- The library is found correctly when running `strace binary`, so that the program manages to print its usage information!

I have never seen an application which behaves differently when run on its own vs in strace, but I figure maybe someone else has seen this happen before? Any ideas how to resolve this?

I don't have the source so I can't rebuild. Running the app in production under strace is probably a non-starter. The OS is RHEL 6.2.

Answer (score 8):

(Old question, but hopefully this will help somebody else)

Under new Linux installations, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not used by the standard system runtime linker for programs with SUID set. It appears that strace, gdb and friends work differently, and *do* use LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

For suid programs, all libraries must be found in the system library cache. Check (as root) whether your "missing" library is present using

```
ldconfig -p | grep <my_library_name>
```

and, if anything's missing, add it to a new file in /etc/ld.so.conf or ld.so.conf.d/ as appropriate, and then rebuild using

```
ldconfig -v
```

Or remove the SUID bit if it's not required, of course.

Comment: Interesting! I will trace back to see if this was the original issue. Out of curiosity, do you have a reference for the SUID/LD_LIBRARY_PATH change?

Comment: Yep - from "man ld.so":

**Using the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Except if the executable is a set-user-ID/set-group-ID binary, in which case it is ignored.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved me a lot of time (and my sanity :) )

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue with setcap binaries - the library was on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ldd was pointing to it. Running in strace also failed but showed it looking only in /lib64 and /usr/lib64 for the library. Removing setcap resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

This really helped me a lot!

I was having a similar problem where libraries were not being picked up properly from the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, even when the ldd command showed all libraries were satisfied.  However, when troubleshooting using strace, it was working.  In my case, however, the problem was that SGID (set group ID sticky bit being on).  When the files were installed, the sysadmin did a recursive chmod that set it on all files (including the executables).  Once the SGID was removed on the executables, the libraries were now found without strace and everything worked as it should using the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.